# C program to calculate a student's grade

Tags: c, if-statement

This is a very simple program, but i don't know why i can't run it properly. After compilation I can manage to ask an input of the student's grade but i cannot run the if statements. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // Write a program that would determine a student's grade based on the set ranges

    float grade;

    printf("Please enter the grade for the student (in percentages) : \n");
    scanf("%f", grade);

    if (grade>=90){
        printf("The student got an A");
    }
    else if (grade>=70 && grade <= 89.99 ){
        printf("The student got a B");
    }
    else if (grade>=50 && grade >= 69.99){
        printf("The student got a C");
    }
    else {
        printf("The student failed");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Does it have options to enable warnings?  Have you turned them all on?  Have you read every one of them?

Comment: GNU GCC compiler. I am using CodeBlocks. There were no warnings.

Comment: You don't need `&& grade <= 89.99`. Since you already tested if it's `>= 90`, it has to be less than that to get to the next test.

Comment: [how to enable full warnings in CodeBlocks](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=134.0)

Comment: Please read http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html.

Comment: The unnecessary check for the upper limit of C grade is incorrect, too -- `>=` instead of `<=`. Another reason to eliminate it.

Comment: @Barmar *You don't need `&& grade <= 89.99`.* It's worse than not needed - it's wrong.  If the user enters `89.994`, for example (and if the `>= 69.99` is changed to `<= 69.99`...) then the program would print `The student failed`.

Comment: but @AndrewHenle, should i remove <= 89.99 so that i wont get "student failed" when i make an input of 89.994

Comment: *i have been programming for the past 12 hours. I am seriously burnt out that i am making these silly mistake* When you reach that point, it's time to turn the computer **off**. More than once I've worked late trying to get something done, failed, went home, came back to work the next day, looked at the code I wrote the night before, and just deleted it. Once you catch yourself making what you called "silly mistakes", it's long past time to give up. A tired brain writes really, really bad code. And yes, remove that `<= 89.99` check - you don't need it as the value is known to be `< 90` by then

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the pointer to the element where you want to save the input:

```
scanf("%f", &grade);
```

Infact you should have a `warning` from your compiler complaining about this (I'm using clang, other compilers may needs some extra flags):

```
warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
scanf("%f", grade);
       ~~   ^~~~~
```

Comment: There were no warnings, this was a silly mistake, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: @MuhtasimRabib as mentioned: _other compilers may needs some extra flags_